# python - Dataframe to SQL Server

Tags: python, sql-server, dataframe

Please don't use sqlalchemy, since I don't have the port info - I have only the server name, db, and username and password.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'num_legs': [2, 4, 8, 0],
               'num_wings': [2, 0, 0, 0],
               'num_specimen_seen': [8, 2, 5, 6]},
             )
print(df)
```

I have a table in SQL Server called `Animal` with columns `Legs`, `wings`, `SpecSeen`;

```
CREATE TABLE Habitat 
(
     Legs int,
     wings int, 
     SpecSeen nvarchar(50)
)

ServerName: SQL15A
Database: Habitat
SQL username: QATuser
Password: ****
```

I need to insert this DataFrame to SQL Server table, also the DataFrame index     column does not need to be inserted into the database table.

Comment: You need the port, whatever tool you are using. SQLAlchemy is excellent - don't write it off. You can try the standard port for SQL server (1433) or you can use a port scanner (nmap) to identify the port

Answer (score 0):

take help from the [here](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/dialects/mssql.html#dialect-mssql-pyodbc-connect)

```
import sqlalchemy
import pyodbc
engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine("mssql+pyodbc://<username>:<password>@<dsnname>")

# write the DataFrame to a table in the sql database
df.to_sql("table_name", engine)
```

Comment: would you check to see how "engine" variable is actually filled out?

Comment: `engine = create_engine(
    "mssql+pyodbc://QATuser:pswd2@mssql2017:1433/Habitat?driver=ODBC+Driver+13+for+SQL+Server",  
    fast_executemany=True)` mssql2017 depends upon the version you are using port 1433 may also varies on some case

Comment: getting this error:   sqlalchemy.exc.InterfaceError: (pyodbc.InterfaceError) ('IM002', '[IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')

Comment: share me the github link i will do and push